# What is the meaning of the two numbers before obj in a PDF?

Tags: pdf

A PDF object starts with `obj` and ends with `endobj`, but in all examples, the specification and real world PDFs, objects also have two numbers in front of them them, like this:

```
1 0 obj
% here is the object defintion
endobj
```

I expected this to be explained in the offical specification (https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/pdfstandards/PDF32000_2008.pdf page 13 and following and page 40), but it is never really explained, or do I miss it completly?

The first number seems to be just a running number, like a unique ID, but what is the second number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is explained in **7.3.10 Indirect Objects**: they are *object number* and *generation number*.